# How to run 2 sql queries in one php if statement?

Tags: php, sql, if-statement

This is the code i have so far

```
if (isset($_POST['button1']))
    {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM UpcomingRota";
        $E1 = $_POST["MondayAMFirstEmployee"]; $E2 = $_POST["MondayAMSecondEmployee"]; $E3 = $_POST["MondayAMThirdEmployee"];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO UpcomingRota (DayAndTime, FirstEmployee, SecondEmployee, ThirdEmployee) VALUES ('MondayAM', '$E1', '$E2', '$E3')";

    }
```

Both the $sql statements work perfectly on there own but when i have both in the if statement it seems to bypass the first one and just run the last $sql statement.

How can i get it to run as many $sql statements as i need it to.... going to have around 15 - 20 in there.

Thanks in advance.

More code as requested.

```
$servername = "db568845851.db.1and1.com";
    $username = "dbo568845851";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "db568845851";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if (isset($_POST['button1']))
    {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM UpcomingRota";
        $E1 = $_POST["MondayAMFirstEmployee"]; $E2 = $_POST["MondayAMSecondEmployee"]; $E3 = $_POST["MondayAMThirdEmployee"];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO UpcomingRota (DayAndTime, FirstEmployee, SecondEmployee, ThirdEmployee) VALUES ('MondayAM', '$E1', '$E2', '$E3')";

    }

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
```

Comment: Well as the code you've posted doesn't actually run any SQL statements, perhaps you should show the real code that isn't working

Comment: You are overwriting $sql value when you set "insert" query without doing anything with $sql = "DELETE FROM UpcomingRota";

Comment: You need to execute the query. Here you're merely setting the `$sql` variable with the query.

Comment: Your code seems incomplete. Please post original code.

Comment: I have just been using this code and it has been working, click the button and the query works... i guess i need to deploy/run the query stored in the $sql variable, how would i do that?

Comment: You should probably remove your password from the code...

Comment: In fact as your password is in the edit history, perhaps you need to change it now

Answer (score 1):

The second statement is overwriting the first one. You can append the second query to the first one using the following syntax:

```
$sql = "First statement;"; // Statements are separated by a ;
$sql .= "Second statement;";

// (Notice the . before the = on the second line)
// $sql now contains "First statement;Second Statement;"
```

You will also need to make sure you are executing the query using a database adapter in a way that supports multi-queries:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: You need to make sure that SQL statements are separated by `;`, so use `$sql .= "; Second statement"`

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM UpcomingRota";
$myResult = mysql_query($sql);
        $E1 = $_POST["MondayAMFirstEmployee"]; $E2 = $_POST["MondayAMSecondEmployee"]; $E3 = $_POST["MondayAMThirdEmployee"];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO UpcomingRota (DayAndTime, FirstEmployee, 
SecondEmployee, ThirdEmployee) VALUES ('MondayAM', '$E1', '$E2', '$E3')";
$myResult = mysql_query($sql);
```

You have to execute the querys.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out because i am just doing lots of inserts into my table i should be doing this.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (column1, column2) VALUES ('data', 'data'), ('data', 'data')
```

and its working so far.